# Rotating direction vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

Given $n$-dimensional unit direction vectors $v_0 = (0, ..., 0, 1)$ and arbitrary $v_1$, how could I rotate a third direction vector $v_2$ by the difference of the orientation between $v_0$ and $v_1$?

In other words I want to apply a rotation on $v_2$ which sends $v_0$ to $v_1$, and fixes any vectors orthogonal to $v_0$ and $v_1$.

What is the simplest solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: To be clear, do you mean the rotation that sends $v_0$ to $v_1$ and fixes all vectors which are orthogonal to $v_0$ and $v_1$?

Comment: Using a 2D analogy, if the rotation between $v_0$ and $v_1$ is $+30°$, then rotate $v_2$ by $+30°$. So yes, the rotation send $v_0$ to $v_1$. Directions $v_i \neq v_0$ will be simply rotated.

Comment: The issue is that in more than two dimensions, there are many different rotations that send $v_0$ to $v_1$.

Comment: "Interpolation" is irrelevant; there are multiple different orthogonal transformations that map $v_0$ to $v_1$.  As a simple example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if $v_0=v_1$, then a rotation of any angle around the $z$ axis will work.

Comment: If $v_0 = v_1$ then there is no difference in orientation, so basically any "axis" would work. In higher dimensions we can't speak about rotational axes, but rotational planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of the rotation you seek is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you're asking for the rotation that maps $v_0$ to $v_1$ via a rotation of plane spanned by $v_0$ and $v_1$, and fixes the orthogonal complement of this plane.  You can describe this transformation explicitly as follows.

First, let us write $a=\langle v_1,v_0\rangle$, $b=\sqrt{1-a^2}$, and $w=\frac{v_1-av_0}{b}$.  (If $a=\pm 1$ so $b=0$, then you can just let $w$ be any unit vector orthogonal to $v_0$.)  Then $\{v_0,w\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the plane spanned by $v_0$ and $v_1$, and $v_1=av_0+bw$.  With respect to this basis, you want the rotation of the plane which has matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}$, since you want to send $v_0$ to $av_0+bw$.

Given $v_2$, let $c=\langle v_2,v_0\rangle$ and $d=\langle v_2,w\rangle$.  The projection of $v_2$ onto the plane of $v_0$ and $v_1$ is then $cv_0+dw$, so you want to apply the rotation matrix above to this projection and fix $v_2-cv_0+dw$, the part of $v_2$ that is orthogonal to the plane.  Thus the rotation you seek sends $v_2$ to $(v_2-cv_0-dw)+(ac-bd)v_0+(ad+bc)w$.

Comment: Can you somewhat explain why does it work? What kind of rotation representation is this?

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation.

Comment: @plasmacel: I do believe this is one way to do a [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) in the new coordinate system (orthonormal basis).

Comment: What kind of orthonormalization is $w=\frac{v_1-av_0}{b}
$ in the answer? It doesn't look like Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: It is exactly Gram-Schmidt, applied to $v_0$ and $v_1$.  Note that $av_0$ is just the projection of $v_0$ onto the span of $v_1$, and $b$ is the norm of $v_1-av_0$

Comment: I have one more question: to combine two rotations $R_0(u_0, v_0, \theta_0)$ and $R_1(u_1, v_1, \theta_1)$, where $u$ and $v$ are orthonormal basis vectors of the plane of rotation and $\theta$ is the angle, one should rotate $u_0$ by $R_0$ and $R_1$ as $w = u_0 R_0 R_1$. Then create a new rotation $R_2$ by the method in your answer as the rotation between the original $u_0$ and this new vector $w$. The resulting rotation is the composition of $R_0$ and $R_1$. Is there any simpler (and computationally more efficient) way to do this?

Comment: @plasmacel: The composition of $R_0$ and $R_1$ will usually _not_ just be a rotation in a plane, so it does not suffice just to compute $w$.  I don't know any particularly efficient way of computing it off the top of my head.

Comment: @EricWofsey Why? After you apply $R_0$ and $R_1$ on a vector $u$ as $u' = u R_0 R_1$, you get a vector. Then you can find an another simple planar rotation $R_2$ between vectors $u$ and $u'$. This is just a rotation between two vectors, and combines $R_0$ and $R_1$, since $u R_0 R_1 = u R_2$.

Comment: It is true that $uR_0R_1=uR_2$, but it isn't necessarily true that $xR_0R_1=xR_2$ for _all_ vectors $x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, I see. Then the best (and maybe the simplest) method do to this is representing $R_0$ and $R_1$ as matrices and multiplying them.