# Find the angle of a higher dimensional rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations, angle

I was trying to find the angle of an arbitrary rotation matrix, and I decided to use the formula for angle between two vectors:

$\theta=\max\limits_{\vec{x}}\left(\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{x}\cdot R\vec{x}}{\left|\vec{x}\right|\left|R\vec{x}\right|}\right)\right)=\max\limits_{\vec{x}}\left(\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{x}\cdot R\vec{x}}{\left|\vec{x}\right|^2}\right)\right)$.

I think that any higher dimensional rotation lies in a unique plane of rotation, which is the plane (through the origin) such that any vector perpendicular to the plane is rotated by 0 degrees (completely unaffected) and any nonzero vector on the plane is rotated by the largest amount, meaning it is a good choice for $\vec{x}$ in the $\theta$ equation. I saw user856's answer for finding the plane of rotation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1894633/869999), which said I could take two linearly independent columns of $R-I$, and these would span the plane (so any nonzero column of $R-I$ would be a good choice of $\vec{x}$ to find $\theta$).

But the question that that answer was posted under repeatedly said that it was limiting the question to just rotations in a single plane, which seemed to imply that not all rotations in higher dimensions are restricted to a single plane, which might mean that this strategy does not always work. I do not understand higher-dimensional rotations very much, so I am not sure.

My plan will work if every rotation in higher dimensions lies in a unique plane through the origin, where vectors perpendicular to this plane are rotated by 0 degrees, and vectors within this plane are rotated by the largest angle. Is this true? And is there anything else wrong with my method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "higher dimensional rotation"? Are you only talking about 3-dimensional rotations?

Comment: Hint: What is the trace of a general rotation matrix?

Comment: If "higher dimensional rotations" refer merely to elements of the [special orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Special_orthogonal_group) (orthogonal matrices with determinant 1), then it is not always true that all rotations "are restricted to a single plane". As an example, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta &0&0\\\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 & 0\\
0&0&\cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi\\
0 & 0 & \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi}
$$
corresponds to two simultaneous rotations in mutually orthogonal planes.

Comment: In general, the number of independent plane rotations that take place in $SO(n)$ is restricted only by the number of mutually orthogonal planes that can exist in $n$-dimensional space, which means that there could be $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ independent planes of rotation, and always a single corresponding "axis" of rotation when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann It looks like you are right. When I plug in $\theta = \phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ to your example matrix, like 
\[\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\]
every vector is rotated by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so there does not exist a plane where vectors perpendicular to the plane are rotated by $0$, so my idea is wrong. I guess I don't fully understand higher dimensional things.