# Signed angle in n-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Given two $n$-dimensional basis vectors $e_0, e_1$ spanning a 2D plane embedded into an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, how to compute the signed angle $\Omega \in [-\pi, \pi]$ between two vectors $u$ and $v$ on this plane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Explanation: a signed angle makes sense only when the plane where the vectors live is endowed with an orientation (which is really the choice of one particular basis once and for all). A positive angle will then mean equivalently that the basis $(u,v)$ defines the same orientation as the one you fixed, which means that the change of basis from one to the other has a positive determinant.

In an $n$-dimensional space, there is no canonical choice of an orientation for each plane. In rough terms, you can look at your vectors from either side of the plane they span, and "see" two opposite angles.

Comment: You can perform rotations in $n$-dimensional space using two basis vectors and an angle (even the angle between two vectors) as described in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1890826/207654. Then you have to be able to calculate the signed angle between two vectors, which is the angle of the rotation you performed.

Comment: @plasmacel Let me make it easier: imagine the two vectors are perpendicular. The signed angle is either $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. Which one do you choose? From which side do you look at them?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You choose the one which will result in the second vector becoming parallel to the first if the second vector is rotated by that angle (or the other way around, as long as you are consistent). The orientation is defined by the ordering of the vectors.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley I'm not sure I can see what you mean. Could you expand further? Perhaps in a new answer if you have a different point of view.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier There are two ways to view the plane, two signs for the angle, and two ways to order the input vectors. The order of the vectors should thus define the plane's orientation, and the sign of the angle. One choice of how to perform that association will produce the angle by which to rotate $v_1$ to make it parallel with $v_2$; the other will give you the opposite-sign, equal-magnitude angle by which to rotate $v_2$ to make it parallel with $v_1$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to compute that except by trial and error. I found this question while looking for the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33920320/12763497) excellent proof, here is how to calculate that angle, called $\beta$ to distinguish it from $\alpha$, the unsigned version of the angle rotated in a certain direction from $\vec{a}$ to $\vec{b}$.  Note that you must specify a vector $\vec{n}$ satisfying $\lVert\vec{n}\rVert = 1$ normal to the plane containing the two angles, which will point in one of the two possible directions:

$\beta = $`atan2`$\left(\left[(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \cdot \vec{n}\right], \left[\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}\right]\right)$,

where `atan2` is a function requiring entry of a fraction in the form $\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\cos{\beta}} \equiv \tan{\beta}$.

Adding images of source material for definitions of cross (skew/vector) and dot (direct/scalar) product from Chapter 5 of [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/R5IKAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) book by J. Willard Gibbs:

[Definition of skew product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZwFU.png)

[How to calculate cross/vector product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ6K3.jpg)

[Definition of direct product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvH7M.jpg)

[Meaning of negative dot product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkyH0.jpg)

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980909/adrian-leonhard for the excellent proof linked above.

Comment: I posted a MATLAB code snippet here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180131-how-can-i-find-the-angle-between-two-vectors-including-directional-information#comment_939096

Comment: You are using cross product of two vectors in this formula. The 2-ary cross-product exists only in 3-dimensional space. In n-dimensional space you need n-1 vectors to do a cross product. How does this answer cover the n-dimensional case?

Comment: @plasmacel you got me there.  I suppose I am not answering the n-dimensional question.  I am posting this because I see n=3 as the most common choice of dimensions, and because I wanted people from this community looking for an answer in that dimension to see the excellent content of SO already out there answering it in that particular case.

Comment: I'm voting to delete this because I think @plasmacel has a valid critique.

Comment: @Integrand how hard would it be for either you or the critique submitter to generalize this?  Change notation to reflect that X means a generalized exterior cross product and let it stand as is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#External_product

Comment: Serious question: how do you define a $n$-dimensional cross product?

Comment: @Integrand TBH I have not had time to look into this.  Just looking to get some cross-pollination between SE sub-sites going and/or appreciated.  It seems obvious that you have to specify a normal vector to the subspace containing the two original vectors, so maybe the external product (of which cross product is a special case?) is the way to go.  Sorry I mean to type external, rather than exterior, in my most recent comment.

Comment: @brethvoice This is not an answer to the original question. Changing notation here doesn't help, since as I said, the n-dimensional cross product requires n-1 vectors. This is why 3-dimensional cross product requires 2. The exterior product you mention produces a bivector, which is (for the same reason) a pseudovector only in 3-dimensional space. You cannot perform n-dimensional cross product, or an exterior product which will produce a pseudovector (which could be mapped back to a vector as its Hodge dual) in general n-dimensions.

Comment: @brethvoice Thanks for your effort to help tho ;]

Comment: @plasmacel I went ahead and suggested an edit to the question itself.  Even though the first answer was that "you can't" do what the OP was asking, the reasons for it all go away in 3-D, and only in 3-D, if you specify one of the two normal vectors to the plane.

Comment: There are other questions for the 3D case. This question was specifically about the n-dimensional case. That time I was into n-dimensional geometry.

Comment: @plasmacel please post a link and I will transfer this answer there to the question about signed angles between 3-D vectors.  In the meantime, if you use MATLAB please check out this function I just uploaded: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/78300-signedangletwovectors

Comment: I edited a 3-D specific question but it is still closed.  I cannot answer a closed question so I am glad this one is not deleted yet.  Here is the question I edited; I am not sure why it is still closed, but the answer clearly shows sine and cosine, which feed directly into the four-quadrant arctangent solution I suggested: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141067/747468